# Multiple Site Manger setup

Tags: multi-site-manager

The published support docs for ExpressionEngine 2 mention purchasing and installing MSM.

Where do I even find these files?

Answer (score 0):

In Expressionengine v3 and up it comes preinstalled. You just have to enable it and purchase a license for each additional site. Go to your general settings and click on the radio button to enable site manager.

[image: Enable Multiple Site Manager first]

Then you will see another option in the dropdown list when you click on Developer called site manager, from which you can name and manage your other sites.

[image: You should now have a new option called site manager]

Comment: Edited my question just now. I have EE 2. Thanks for the info though, we may just need to consider upgrading to 3.